# ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64'). How to handle this error?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, linear-regression, valueerror

In dataset first i replaced all missing values with imputer class using mean strategy but it has replaced that with large values in dataset which is resulting into this error. What could be the solution for this or how can  i round up values to 2 decimal places. As dataset is containing float values rounding up them to 2 or 3 decimal place would work for me.

Code :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt


df=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/asus/Desktop/Life Expectancy Data.csv")
X=df.iloc[:, 4:].values
Y=df.iloc[:,3:4].values

from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imputer=SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan,strategy='mean')
imputer.fit(X)
X=imputer.transform(X)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test=train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
reg=LinearRegression()
reg.fit(X_train,Y_train)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
X_train.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan, inplace=True)
```

use the above

then replace null value by

```
X_train.fillna(999, inplace=True)
```

or

```
X_train.fillna(X_train.mean(), inplace=True)
```